# JQuery when done not stopping execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have this bit of code, and what I would like to do is executing function0 only after function1 has completed as returned the flag that I need, but I'm not being able to do it. The when().done() on function0 is always executing on the first run and makes the rest of my code execute.

function0 summed up

```
function0: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var valid = false;

        var dfd = $.Deferred();
        $.when(function1(e)).done(function(v){
            valid = v; // -> right here valid is undefined
            dfd.resolve();
        });

        dfd.promise();

        if(!valid) {
            alertSomething();
            return;
        }

        keepExecutingCode();
    },
```

function1 summed up

```
function1: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();            
            var df = $.Deferred();
            var flag = true;
            App.resetDiv('#div');
            getSomething();
            getSomething2();
            $.when(getSomething3()).done(function(){
                $.when(getSomething4()).done(function(){
                    if (cond1()){
                        doSomething5();                
                        if (cond2()){
                            $.when(doSomething6(),doSomething7()).done(function(var1, var2){
                                doSomething8(var1,var2);
                                flag = true;
                                updateSomething();
                            });
                        }else{
                            flag = false;
                            updateSomething2();
                        }
                    }else{ flag2 = false;
                        showSomething();
                        flag3 = false;
                    }
                    df.resolve(flag);
                });
            //PROBLEM 1 RIGHT HERE
            //df.promise();
            //return flag;
            });
        // it should be
        return df.promise();
        },
```

I am aware that the problem might be with the deferreds on the other functions, because inside function0 it always does the resolve even without the v value and once it gets to `if(!valid)` valid is undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

> Update - It's solved

```
function0: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var valid = false;

    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    //$.when(function1(e)).done(function(v){
    // had to change .done to .then
    $.when(function1(e)).then(function(v){
        valid = v; // -> right here valid is undefined
        if(!valid) {
            alertSomething();
            return;
        }
        // had to change the scope and make it inside the .then so that it only executes when I have the value
        keepExecutingCode();
        dfd.resolve();
    });

    dfd.promise();


},
```

Also had to change both .done in function1 to .then

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: thats how async works...
you running fuction0, where function1 executes in async way, so your if statement runs before your function1 executes

Comment: yes, I understand that, but in this case I need it to be synced. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your'e not catching the error events of your deferreds. (Depending on your jQuery-Version,) you can do this in two ways:

- Use the [.fail](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/)-callback 
  Here you add it after your done-callback so you can respond to the reject-callback of your deferred
- Replace .done with [.then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) and use the second callback 
  Here you just insert your function for handling errors into the second parameter of the then-function

Comment: should I replace it on both functions? because it is still not working :(